# XML Schema regular expression for specifying ASCII range

Tags: regex, xsd, schema, w3c

I am trying to place a restriction using regular expression and xsd:pattern to only allow characters that fall within a certain range of ASCII values with a maximum of 10 characters. Specifically from ASCII value 33 to 126.

As of now, i have the following snippet which i am trying to modify.

```
<xsd:simpleType name="Name">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:pattern value="[(\p{L}|\d)._-]{0,9}"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

The other option that i have is to list out individual ASCII chars from 33 to 126 in the regular expression. As of now, i am resisting from taking that path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid listing all the choices, you can use a range (as already suggested by Ismail Ghalimi):

```
<xsd:pattern value="[!-~]{0,10}"/>
```

Or, since the range you list is essentially the entire set of non-whitespace characters in ASCII, you can use the Unicode block name Basic Latin and a simple character-class subtraction.  And you can move the length constraint to a separate facet:

```
<xsd:maxLength value="10"/>
<xsd:pattern value="[\p{IsBasicLatin}-[\s]]*"/>
```

Note in passing that in XSD regular expressions are written without anchors, so no ^ is needed at the beginning and no $ at the end:  either the pattern matches the entire literal, or the literal is not type-valid.

Comment: Michael, aren't you missing an asterisk? [\p{IsBasicLatin}-[\s]]*

Answer (score 3):

Using a range like `[!-~]{0,10}` should do the trick.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: Sorry - I meant to abandon that comment entirely.  No slashes, no ^, and no $ needed in XSD (and if present, they are interpreted as requiring that the string should begin with the literal string "`/^`", continue with zero to ten ASCII printable characters, and conclude with the literal string "`$/`").

Comment: Yup. C. M. Sperberg-McQueen's suggestion worked. <xsd:pattern value="[!-~]{0,10}"/> is what i went with. Thanks Ismael !!